# How to add dummy data to an Adwords test account?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm working with the Adwords API and I need to get data (Clicks/Impressions/etc) from my test account, are there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add dummy data to your Google adwords account.
Using test account you can download reports with zero stats.